# mobile application with heartbeat mechanism

Tags: android, performance, mobile

My requirement is I need to update mobile status(Available, Switched off, in a call, flight mode) from a mobile application to third party application through web service.
But when we change the phone to flight mode, we get the event, but the data connection would be shut off by then and we cannot make a web service call. Another difficult situation is when we go out of range we will receive an event saying there is no connectivity so I update my presence over a web service call.
So we planned to have  a heartbeat. Every minute, lets say the mobile application would make a web service call saying I’m available. If the server do not receive this event at any interval then the server can assume that the client either went out of charge or range or he went into flight mode. The moment the phone is turned back on he will automatically start sending heartbeats.

Whether the heartbeat will dry out the charge of the mobile shortly. Is there any other disadvantage in heartbeat mechanism?